# Metric spaces bounded sets equivalence

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Let X be a a non empty metric space and suppose A $\subseteq$ X. 
Then A is bounded if $\exists$ $z$  $\exists$ $r>0$ so that $A \subseteq B(z,r)$.

WTS The following are equivalent:

1) A is bounded

2) for each x in X there exists a radius r>0 so that A is contained within $B(x,r)$.

3)$diam(A)$ is finite

My proof:

(1) implies (2):

Suppose (1) holds.  This means that  there exists a $z \in X$ and $r>0$ so that whenever $b \in A$ we have $d(b,z)<r$. So suppose x in X is arbitrary. We observe that whenever $a \in A$, $d(a,x) \leq d(a,z) +d(z,x)$ $< r + d(z,x)$. And so for $s=r +d(z,x)$ we have that whenever $a \in A$, $a \in B(x, r+ d(z,x))$.

(2) implies (3):
 Suppose 2 holds. Let $a,b \in A$ be arbitrary. That means A is contained within $B(a,r_1)$ and also contained within $B(b,r_2)$ for some $r_1,r_2 >0$, and so by the triangle inequality, $d(a,b) < r_1+r_1=2r_1$ and the set {d(a,b) | a,b $\in A$ } is bounded above and so by the axiom of completeness, must have a supremum. Therefore the diameter of A is finite.

(3) implies (1):
Suppose that $diam(A)$ is finite. Assume for the sake of contradiction that for each $ x\in X$ and for every $r>0$. A is not contained in $B(x,r)$. That means there exists an element $ a\in A$ so that $d(a,x)>r$. Since that holds for each x in X and A is a subset of X, it holds for each element of A, and so the diameter is not finite, hence a contradiction.

Please tell me if this proof is correct. Also, I would like as much feedback on this proof as possible. I've worked on this and put effort, so I'd very much love feedback, please.

Comment: (1) implies (2) seems fine. But (2) implies (3) seems to have a flaw. You started by letting $a,b \in A$ be arbitrary, then you claim there exist $r_1, r_2 > 0 $ ... This means your choice of $r_1, r_2$ depend on the initial points $a,b$. Hence $2r_1$ is not a uniform bound on the set of distances.

Comment: It would be better if you first fixed a point $p \in A$, then say there exists an $r>0$ ... After that, let $a,b \in A$ be arbitrary; then conclude that $d(a,b) < 2r$. This way, the bound $2r$ on the set of distances does not depend on the points $a,b$.

Comment: Also, for (3) implies (1), while I agree that the contradiction you would arrive at is the diameter being infinite, I can't see how you arrived at that conclusion. (The first two parts were proven in more detail, so you should try to prove it in just as much detail) By the way, there's a quicker proof for it: fix a point $p \in A$, and put $r  = \text{diam}(A)$... here we're choosing the diameter of the set to be the radius of the ball, so even from an english standpoint it should be clear why this ought to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 to 2 seems OK enough, though I'd formulate it more succinctly. Suppose $A \subseteq B(z,R)$ for some $z \in X, R>0$. Then if $x \in X$ is arbitrary,

$$A \subseteq B(x, d(x,z)+R)$$ by the triangle inequality and so the radius for $x$ can be taken as $d(x,z)+R$.

2 to 3. is similar: Fix $a_0 \in A$ and use $2$ to find $R>0$ such that $ A \subseteq B(a_0,R)$ and if $a,b\in A$ then $d(a,b) \le d(a_0,a) + d(a_0,b) < 2R$ and so $2R$ is an upper bound for $\{d(x,y): x \in A, y \in A\}$ and so $\operatorname{diam}(A) \le 2R$ is finite.

You cannot take $r$'s depending on the variable $a,b$ as you do, you need a fixed point and its fixed radius to get an unvarying upperbound. So the direct definition of bounded already suffices.

3 to 1 is easier than you think. Let $R = \operatorname{diam}(A)$, which is a well-defined real number, and pick any $a_0 \in A$. Then for $a \in A$, $d(a,a_0) \le R < R+1$ so $a_0$ and the fact that $$A \subseteq B(a_0,R+1)$$ shows that $A$ is bounded.

Don't go for contradictions where a straight application of the defintion is enough.